# ZendFramework echo a form in custom action

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a controller with this action below:

```
public function addAction()
{
    //action for the comments submission
    $form = new Application_Form_Comment();
    $form->submit->setLabel('Comment');
    $this->view->form = $form;
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
        $comment = new Application_Model_DbTable_Comments();
        $comment->addComment($formData['comment'], $id);
            $this->_helper->redirector('index');
        } else {
            $form->populate($formData);
        }
    }
```

In my view if I echo $this->form;
The form doesn't show.

Rik

Comment: In the view, what does `var_dump($this->form);` yield?  It may not make a difference (I'm not sure), but I always assign my form to the view near *after* calling isValid/populate or adding errors to it.  That may not be the problem though.  I'm curious to see what the var_dump shows.

Comment: NULL, if I have the above code in my index action the form shows. But its clashing with the code so I need it in its own action.

Comment: no errors or exceptions, sorry I should have stated that the form needs to be in the index.phtml file but the code needs to be seperate from the indexAction.

Comment: So you have this code in the addAction of the indexController, but you want to echo it out into index.phtml?

Comment: @user1329580 That's the problem, if the form code is in addAction, but you are accessing index(Action), then the code in addAction is not executed so you have no form object created.  You can use some sort of helper (action or view), or in your indexAction, call `$this->addAction()` to execute the code in that block.  I would go with another method though since it sounds like you don't want people to access index/add directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to separate the form from any particular controller, you could use a view helper. [Writing your own is quite easy](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.custom).

Create the file `application/views/helpers/CommentForm.php` which will contain:-

```
class Zend_View_Helper_CommentForm extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function commentForm()
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_Comment();
        return $form;
    }
}
```

Then in whichever view you need it in just do:-

```
echo $this->commentForm();
```

Which will render your form.

Comment: I need the code in the addAction();

Comment: Updated answer for you. Also note correction to file name. Sorry.

Comment: @vascowhite I think it's a dead end solution. Seems comfortable but what about populating or validating this form? If you want to move creating form to helper I think it'd be better to create Action Helper not View Helper. (check this article http://devzone.zend.com/1218/action-helpers-in-zend-framework/)

Comment: In this case a view helper is fine, its just a comment form, when did you ever need to pre-populate a comment form? An action helper would be suitable for something more complex, but would be overkill in this situation as it takes a bit more setting up.

Comment: You cleverly omitted validation part of my question to prove Your point, didn't You? ;] As we can see from code in question dude wanted to validate this form.

Comment: The form will still submit to addAction() and be validated there. I'm not trying to prove a point, I didn't make one. I just gave the guy advice which he accepted. If you prefer a different solution post your own answer rather than trying to force me to defend mine.

Comment: @vascowhite my comment wasn't meant to be offensive (if You felt it was). I just don't think it's good approach to have to create view helper for every form which doesn't give You any benefits (You won't use it in controller to fabricate form and, for example, validate it)